# uninstall python 2.7.6 and install 2.6 instead

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to uninstall python 2.7.6 and install 2.6 instead. how can I manage that. which python command gives (/usr/bin/python). my environment is ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could try:</strike>

apt-get remove python2.7

Don't remove python 2.7, instead have both at the same time

Insert the following in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main
```

Or use another PPA of your choice. Then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python2.6
```

Disclaimer: The PPA is just one I found on Google, no guarantees.

Comment: You *don't* remove python2.7 in versions of Ubuntu before 16.04. Too many things depend it on. It's a nice way to nuke your desktop.

Comment: it is quite late answer. Many part of the system have been broken and I am trying to figure out how to fix that

Comment: Do you have any suggestions !!!

Comment: Can't you just reinstall it again?  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`

Comment: once the system collapse the terminal is gone and everything went bad. I had to re-install ubuntu :)

Comment: @OmarAli You could have used a live-cd and and chrooted into the system to reinstall missing packages.